# How to Disable Double Tapping?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-2, lock-screens

My Galaxy S2 asked me to double-tap and drag to unlock (instead of just dragging) and every time I try to tap anything, one tap only makes a yellow box appear around the app or file or whatever, which is really difficult to deal with and annoying.

Comment: Could it be you've played with the developer options? Though I've never heard of that side-effect, the "yellow box" reminds me of some "feedback" which can be enabled there.

Comment: Are you using Accessibility options?

Answer (score 2):

Go into the device settings, then from **My device**, choose **Accessibility**. From that menu, press **TalkBack**, then click the switch in the top-right corner to turn TalkBack off.

After tapping something once to get the yellow box (and the spoken description of what the thing is), double-tap anywhere on the screen to click the highlighted thing.

Comment: But I can't scroll down to the accessibility settings. Double tapping also locked the scroll-down. Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

The steps to disable double tap to unlock

1. Go to Applications
2. Go to Settings
3. Go to Accessibility
4. Select Talk Back and turn off Once the talk back has been disabled.

   you do not need to keep on doing double tap.

Answer (score 1):

On some Android phones, you can disable TalkBack by holding Vol+ and Vol- for a few seconds.

Answer (score 0):

On Samsung Galaxy Y Plus (GT-S5303), follow these steps to remove the double tap:

1. Go to Settings
2. Choose My device
3. Tap Lock Screen
4. Go to Screen security lock